# Strange Spring @SessionAttributes Behavior

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, session-state, tomcat7

I'm using @SessionAttributes on 2 controllers and am experiencing some very strange behavior. My first controller (ViewController) is simply a view controller that displays JSP pages. The other is a controller that handles Ajax requests (AjaxController). I have a session attribute that is simply an object that has a HashMap as a member. The object is a wrapper around the map. The map is populated from the database and put in the session, which displays fine via the ViewController. However, when I do a delete from the map via an ajax request (AjaxController) and refresh the page, ViewController SOMETIMES shows that the element is removed, yet other times the element is still there. Here's code snippets:

**ViewController** (the homepage simply displays the contents of the map contained by userSettings

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"userSettings"})
public class ViewController {

@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(ModelMap model) {
        UserSettings userSettings = (UserSettings) model.get("userSettings");
        String userListenersJson = userSettings.toJson();  // for bootsrtapping the js on the front end

        return "views/home";
    }
}
```

AjaxController:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"userSettings"})
public class AjaxController {

@RequestMapping(value="/users/listeners/{externalId}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
public @ResponseBody
AjaxResponse<?> deleteListener(ModelMap model,
        @PathVariable long externalId) {

            UserSettings userSettings = (UserSettings) model.get("userSettings");
            userSettings.removeSetting(externalId);
            return new AjaxResponse<String>(null, true);    
}
}
```

Am I using @SessionAttributes wrong here? Why would this work sometimes and not others? I've also tried putting all of the view and ajax functionality in the same controller and experienced the same behavior.

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT:**

I've refactored my code a bit to use the UserPrincipal via springsecurity. My understanding is that this object is stored in the session. Regardless, I'm seeing exactly the same behavior.

Here's the UserPrincipal constructor that populates the user settings map. I've set breakpoints here to ensure that the correct listenerDBOs are set - they are, every time. This is the only time the listeners get set from the db into the UserSettings object in CustomUserPrincipal. All other adds/removes are done via the controllers (quick aside: adds never fail... only removes):

```
public CustomUserPrincipal(UserDBO userDBO) {
    // set UserSettings obj
    UserSettingsAdapter.addListeners(userDBO.getUserListenerDBOs(), userSettings);
}
```

The UserSettings object itself:

```
public class UserSettings implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1882864351438544088L;
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(UserSettings.class);

    private Map<Long, Listener> userListeners = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<Long, Listener>(1));

    // get the listeners as an arraylist
    public List<Listener> userListeners() {
        return new ArrayList<Listener>(userListeners.values());
    }

    public Map<Long, Listener> getUserListeners() {
        return userListeners;
    }

    public Listener addListener(Listener listener) {
        userListeners.put(listener.getId(), listener);
        return listener;
    }

    // I'm logging here to try and debug the issue. I do see the success
    // message each time this function is called
    public Listener removeListener(Long id) {
        Listener l = userListeners.remove(id);
        if (l == null) {
            log.info("failed to remove listener with id " + id);
        } else {
            log.info("successfully removed listener with id " + id);
        }

        log.info("Resulting map: " + userListeners.toString());
        log.info("Map hashcode: " + userListeners.hashCode());

        return l;
    }


    public Listener getListener(long id) {
        return userListeners.get(id);
    }
  }
```

This is the helper function in the UserSettingsAdapter class that adds to the UserSettings object, called from CustomUserDetails constructor:

```
public static void addListeners(Set<UserListenerDBO> userListeners, UserSettings userSettings) {
    for (UserListenerDBO userListenerDBO : userListeners) {
        if (userListenerDBO.isActive()) {
            addListener(userListenerDBO, userSettings);
        }
    }
}
```

I've also changed the controller code to user the CustomUserPrincipal object instead of @SessionAttributes:

In ViewController:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(ModelMap model) {
   CustomUserPrincipal userPrincipal = authenticationHelpers.getUserPrincipal();
   UserSettings userSettings = userPrincipal.getUserSettings();
   String userListenersJson = userSettings.toJson();
   return "views/home";
}
```

In AjaxController:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/users/listeners/{externalId}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
public @ResponseBody
AjaxResponse<?> deleteListener(ModelMap model,
        @PathVariable long externalId) {
   CustomUserPrincipal userPrincipal = authenticationHelpers.getUserPrincipal();
   UserSettings userSettings = userPrincipal.getUserSettings();
   userSettings.removeListener(externalId);

   return new AjaxResponse<String>(null, true); 
}
```

I hope this helps shed some light on the issue!

Comment: [@SessionAttributes Problem](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?49396-SessionAttribute-problems) you may want to look this

Comment: Thanks for the link. Thing is, the way that thread is saying @SessionAttributes works is different from the behavior I'm seeing. The object is there in both controllers, but when I remove a setting via userSettings.removeSetting(..) it sometimes removes and sometimes does not.

Comment: "Each Controller has it's own ModelMap so something put as a @SessionAttributes in controller1 isn't available in controller2 and vice versa. For that to work you will have to put stuff on the session manually yourself." -from the link above

Comment: That's also not the behavior I'm seeing. When I set the attribute in the ViewController it is in the model when requests come in to the AjaxController. That being the case, perhaps it's still wrong to do access the attribute across controllers? Additionally, it may be helpful to add that I'm seeing the same behavior when I store all of this stuff in the UserPrincipal (SpringSecurity). Is this also incorrect usage?

Comment: Where is userSettings populated from the database?  Can you provide this code, and also the code for the removeSetting method?

Comment: Where is authenticationHelpers declared?

Comment: AuthenticationHelpers is simply a static class that provides helper function to get the security context and UserPrincipal. I can provide the code if you think it's necessary. What's strange in all of this is that adding to the map always works. Deletes are the only problem. If I add 10 items to the map 9 of them will delete ok, yet the 10th will take several times before the delete "sticks".

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with @SessionAttributes.  A controller had a @SessionAttributes annotation at the class level, and one of the methods handled POST requests, and included an instance of the session-managed object as an argument.  This instance was saved to the database, but was re-used by subsequent requests, causing some data corruption.  We had to add another method argument of type SessionStatus, and call `SessionStatus.setComplete()`.  This caused the instance to be removed from the session, and prevented reuse and corruption.  So try adding a SessionStatus instance to your controllers' handler methods, and invoke setComplete() where appropriate.

EDIT: I accidentally referenced the getter `isComplete()` in my initial answer; I meant to reference the setter `setComplete()`.

Comment: I tried both setComplete() and isComplete() and the behavior didn't change. If I delete from a map in the session it takes anywhere from 1 to n attempts to "stick".

Answer (score 0):

@SessionAttributes is specific to a Controller and is not shared among several Controllers.
Instead, consider using manually session.setAttribute (class HttpSession).

You should have a look here : http://beholdtheapocalypse.blogspot.fr/2013/01/spring-mvc-framework-sessionattributes.html